# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in line 32

Tags: php

I am attempting to submit a form and I keep receiving errors for this line of code, which I have used in another form and worked perfectly fine. Please guide me on what to do as i'm new to PHP and I will be eternally grateful!

```
$quantity=$_POST['r_quantity'];
$name=$_POST['r_firstname'];
$sname=$_POST['r_lastname'];
$tel=$_POST['r_telno'];
$email=$_POST['r_email'];
$party=$_GET['eventName'];





 if (!$name or !$sname or !$tel or !$email or !$quantity)
    {
        echo "<p>Your form is incomplete ";
        echo "<br>Please fill in details ";
        include("footlayout.html");

    }
    else

    {
    $SQL="insert into Bookings(customerFName, customerSName, customerTelNo, customerEmail, tickets) values ('".$name."','".$sname."','".$tel."','".$email."','".$quantity."')";
    $exeSQL=mysql_query($SQL);

    echo"Thank you for booking ";
    }


    $ASQL="select Quantity from PARTY where Name='$party'";
    $exeASQL=mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());
    $array=mysql_fetch_array($exeASQL);
    $quantity=$array['r_quantity'];

    if ($ticket>$quantity)
    {
    echo"Sorry There are only:" .$quantity;
    include("footlayout.html");
    exit;
    }

    echo"Thank you for booking tickets to";
    echo $party;
```

EDIT: After making the changes both messages show "Thank you for booking" AND "Sorry there are only:" also both values within the variables don't appear. How could I fix this? Do I put another 'or' in?

Comment: If you would stick to formatting your code you would have seen this yourself.

Comment: you also missed this $party=$_GET['eventName'] its lacking a ;

Comment: Thanks Dave and Abhik :) I edited the code with a new problem if you could have a look? i'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Replace that:

```
{$ASQL="select Quantity from PARTY where Name='$party'";
$exeASQL=mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());
$array=mysql_fetch_array($exeASQL);
$quantity=$array['r_quantity'];
```

With

```
$ASQL="select Quantity from PARTY where Name='$party'";
$exeASQL=mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());
$array=mysql_fetch_array($exeASQL);
$quantity=$array['r_quantity'];
```

(Delete the brace before "$ASQL")

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I made the changes, however I stil receive an error for:  if (!$name or !$sname or !$tel or !$email or !$quantity)

Comment: Don't forget to replace: $party=$_GET['eventName'] with $party=$_GET['eventName'];

Comment: Sorry I have one more issue if you could help? I edited the above post!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (!$name || !$sname || !$tel || !$email || !$quantity)
{
    echo "<p>Your form is incomplete ";
    echo "<br>Please fill in details ";
    include("footlayout.html");

}
else

{
$SQL="insert into EventBookings(customerFName, customerSName, customerTelNo, customerEmail, tickets) values ('".$name."','".$sname."','".$tel."','".$email."','".$quantity."')";
$exeSQL=mysql_query($SQL);

echo"Thank you for booking ";
}


{$ASQL="select Quantity from PARTY where Name='$party'";
$exeASQL=mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());
$array=mysql_fetch_array($exeASQL);
$quantity=$array['r_quantity'];

if ($ticket>$quantity)
{
echo "Sorry There are only:".$quantity;
include("footlayout.html");
exit;
}

echo"Thank you for booking tickets to";
echo $party;
```

Your mistake:

```
echo"Sorry There are only:" $quantity;
```

Need to use:

```
echo "Sorry There are only:" . $quantity;
```

Maybe you need to use "||" instead of "OR".

Comment: Thanks I fixed that! I am still receiving an error however for line 32 which is: if (!$name or !$sname or !$tel or !$email or !$quantity)

Comment: Maybe you need to use "||" instead of "OR".

Answer (score 1):

please change the code

```
 echo"Sorry There are only:". $quantity;
```